# ¿Cómo obtener de una columna de una tabla solo los valores que se incrementan cada "n" valores en mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Por ejemplo si tengo una tabla con registros y uno de los campos tiene valores double como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo por ejemplo presentar los registros cada 0.5 del valor. que el resultado sea algo como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O si deseo que el valor sea cada 0.3, tenga como resultado algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría tener esta respuesta en un select o en un procedimiento almacenado?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Código para pruebas:

```
create table test.secuence(
 id_secuence int auto_increment,
 value text,
 primary key(id_secuence)
);

insert into test.secuence(value) values('1');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('1.1');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('1.5');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('1.7');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('1.9');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('2');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('2.0');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('2.2');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('2.9');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('3');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('3.1');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('3.2');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('3.3');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('3.8');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('3.9');
insert into test.secuence(value) values('4.0');
```

He intentado el escenario presentado en las respuestas pero no he obtenido una respuesta concreta.
La idea es que teniendo una secuencia de valores, expresada en la pregunta anteriormente, sea una secuencia ordenada o una secuencia con saltos (1.0, 1.1, 1.5, 1.6...), poder sacar los valores que deseo dependiendo de el numero de n saltos que necesite, en las respuestas la logica esta super bien explicada, y eso es lo que necesito por ejemplo si quiero los valores de 0.1 en 0.1, o cada valores de 2 en 2, etc.

Realice lo siguiente con el siguiente resultado:

El la primera respuesta funciono, pero en casos de haber saltos en los valores de la secuencia, lamentablemente se distorsiona el resultado, esto porque los valores los toma con respecto a los valores generados por @rownum
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La actualización al aplicarla no logro tener los resultados deseados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intente hacerlo para los valores enteros, en el cual si funcionan, pero lo que necesito pues es que sean filtros tanto en valores decimales, como de valores enteros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, lamentablemente no es la solución que busco. Te agradezco.

Comment: Eh actualizado la pregunta y he agregado un ejemplo mas.
En teoría si tengo una tabla con un campo que esta con información desde el numero 1 hasta el 100, pero separados por decimales en cada registro, por ejemplo:
1 registro: 1.0
2 registro: 1.1
Así sucesivamente hasta el 100.0 

Pero me gustaría traer solo la información dado un step de estos valores.
Esto quiere decir que si elijo un step=1; los valores que tendría serian: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, etc.
Si el step es 0.3, tendría: 1.0, 1.3, 1.6, etc...
Si el step es 0.7 tendría: 1.0, 1.7, 2.4, 3.1, etc...

Comment: Marcos, te puse una nueva respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: Hola Marcos, me puedes servir si te sirvio la respuesta dada y se resolvio tu problema, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En **Oracle** existe la **seudocolumna rownum** la cual asigna un número a cada fila, pero en **MySQL** la cosa es distinta, aunque en **MySQL** esta característica se incorporó a partir de la **versión 8.0**, no obstante esta característica puede ser simulada de una manera fácil.

```
 select t.Values, t.Data from
 (
    select @rownum:= @rownum + 1 as rownum, tabla.*
    from (select @rownum:= -1) r, tabla
 ) t
 where rownum % x = 0
```

En la **consulta interna** declaramos la **variable rownum** y la inicializamos en **-1**. Esta **variable rownum** es la que nos va a servir para otorgarle un numero consecutivo y único a cada fila de la tabla y es esta **variable rownum** la que usaremos para filtrar por el criterio que deseas cada fila.

Sobre los resultados que arroja esta **subconsulta** hacemos entonces una consulta poniendo la condición

```
where rownum % x = 0
```

La **x** representa un numero cualquiera, por ejemplo si queremos obtener los valores **1, 1.3, 1.6, etc.**. tienes que sustituir la **x** por **3**, si quieres que sea **1, 1.5, 2, etc.** la **x** tienes que sustituirla por **5**. Y así sustituirías la **x** por cualquier numero que te construya la secuencia q deseas obtener.

**Actualización:**

```
select * 
from tabla 
where (value - 1) % x = 0
```

Aquí la **x** representa cualquier valor, por ejemplo si quieres obtener
la secuencia **1**, **1.5**, **2**, **2.5**... el valor de **x** sería **0.5**.

Para la secuencia **1**, **1.3**, **1.6**, **1.9** ... el valor de **x** sería **0.3**.

Para la secuencia **1**, **1.2**, **1.4**, **1.6**, **1.8** ... el valor de **x** sería **0.2**.

Comment: Si tienes un salto entre los valores, no funciona. 
Por ejemplo que exista una secuencia de valores (Values) "3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 3.5, etc." el resultado con la lógica que planteada es "3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.7, etc".

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero leiste bien el parrafo final de mi respuesta?

Comment: Si lo hice, pero lamentablemente no funciono.

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero q resultado quieres obtener exactamente para tratar de reproducirlo

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero revisa lo nuevo q puse

Comment: he realizado una actualización a la pregunta, para poner en contexto los resultados obtenidos.

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero revisa el nuevo codigo que puse